# how to change particle color randomly?

Tags: andengine, particles

I'm creating a live wallpaper using andengine. By using ColorParticleModifier, I can change the color of the particles. But how can I make them change color randomly by themselves?

Thank you!

Comment: From Where you start making Live Wallpaper.Can Share@Tony Tong

Comment: what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: guide lines or article to start making live wallpaper..

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to change color over time, you could create a new Particle class and Override onUpdate and place your color changing code in there. Doing this will allow you to have the particle change color every time onUpdate is run.

```
private float colorTimer = 0;
private final float COLOR_RESET = 0.25f;  //change color 4 times per second
private Random rand = new Random();
...

@Override
protected void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed){

    colorTimer += pSecondsElapsed;
        if (colorTimer >= COLOR_RESET){
            colorTimer =0;
            this.mEntity.setColor(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat());
         }

    super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);  
 }
```